# Tokenizer programme in C

Tags: c, arrays, tokenize

I just started to learn how to programme in C and I was asked to code a tokenizer programme, which splits up the words in a sentence into different tokens, basically what strtok() does.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int tokenise(char str[], int start, char result[]);
int main(){
    const int MAX_STRING = 256;
    char buffer[MAX_STRING];
    int start;
    int count;
    int i;
    char result[MAX_STRING];
    fgets(buffer, MAX_STRING, stdin);
    printf("%s\n", buffer);
    start = tokenise(buffer, 0, result);
    while(start != -1){
    printf("%s\n", result);
        start = tokenise(buffer, start, result);
}
int tokenise(char str[], int start, char result[])
{
    int j;
    for( i = start; str[i] != ' '; i++)
    {
       result[j] = str[i];
       j++;
    }
    j = 0;
   return -1;
}
}
```

This is the code I have so far and I don't understand why my function doesn't work.
Is there something basic I did wrong or have I got something massively wrong?
I am also confused as to why my lecturer has

```
start = tokenise(buffer, 0 , result);
```

right above the while loop.
Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You always return `-1` no matter the outcome of the function.
- You don't look for line feed `'\n'` and other such white space characters. Consider using the `isspace()` function in ctype.h.
- You don't look for the end of the string, `'\0'`, meaning that if there are no spaces in the string, your program will crash.

Answer (score 1):

Other than problems [Lundin mentioned in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33101401/tokenizer-programme-in-c/33101497#33101497) ,

In function `int tokenise(char str[], int start, char result[])`

```
int j;
```

`j` is uninitialized , but then also incremented in loop .  Initialzed `j` to `0` before using it otherwise it will have indeterminate value.

Also due to wrong placement of `{ }` your function `tokenize` is defined inside `main`. Define it outside `main`, which is usually done.